# 2 кнопки генерируют одну функцию C#

Tags: c#

Есть 2 кнопки на форме, нажимаю 2 раза на одну из них что бы та в свой черед сгенерировала функцию обработки нажатия. Таким же образом поступаю и со 2-й кнопкой и меня перекидывает на функцию созданную 1-й кнопкой. Что делать? Удаление, на моё удивление не помогает.

Code of Form:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    partial class main_form
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.panel1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.btnClose = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panel2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.pictureBox1 = new System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox();
            this.panelNews = new System.Windows.Forms.Panel();
            this.labelNews = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.btnMinimize = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.panel1.SuspendLayout();
            this.panel2.SuspendLayout();
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).BeginInit();
            this.panelNews.SuspendLayout();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // panel1
            // 
            this.panel1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(61)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(190)))));
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btnMinimize);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.btnClose);
            this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.panel2);
            this.panel1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Top;
            this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
            this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(926, 35);
            this.panel1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.panel1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.panel1_Paint);
            // 
            // btnClose
            // 
            this.btnClose.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.btnClose.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnClose.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 14F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnClose.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cornsilk;
            this.btnClose.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(819, 0);
            this.btnClose.Name = "btnClose";
            this.btnClose.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 35);
            this.btnClose.TabIndex = 0;
            this.btnClose.Text = "X";
            this.btnClose.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnClose.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnClose_Click);
            // 
            // panel2
            // 
            this.panel2.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
            this.panel2.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
            this.panel2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
            this.panel2.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.panel2.Name = "panel2";
            this.panel2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(80, 35);
            this.panel2.TabIndex = 0;
            this.panel2.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.panel2_Paint);
            // 
            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this.pictureBox1.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Right;
            this.pictureBox1.Image = global::WindowsFormsApp2.Properties.Resources.icons8_full_moon_96;
            this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(30, 0);
            this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
            this.pictureBox1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(5);
            this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 35);
            this.pictureBox1.SizeMode = System.Windows.Forms.PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
            // 
            // panelNews
            // 
            this.panelNews.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(61)))), ((int)(((byte)(138)))), ((int)(((byte)(190)))));
            this.panelNews.Controls.Add(this.labelNews);
            this.panelNews.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(55, 68);
            this.panelNews.Name = "panelNews";
            this.panelNews.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(364, 433);
            this.panelNews.TabIndex = 1;
            // 
            // labelNews
            // 
            this.labelNews.AutoSize = true;
            this.labelNews.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("SFNS Display", 27.75F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(220)));
            this.labelNews.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Snow;
            this.labelNews.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(81, 26);
            this.labelNews.Name = "labelNews";
            this.labelNews.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(203, 44);
            this.labelNews.TabIndex = 0;
            this.labelNews.Text = "НОВОСТИ";
            // 
            // btnMinimize
            // 
            this.btnMinimize.FlatAppearance.BorderSize = 0;
            this.btnMinimize.FlatStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FlatStyle.Flat;
            this.btnMinimize.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial Rounded MT Bold", 14F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
            this.btnMinimize.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Cornsilk;
            this.btnMinimize.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(738, -3);
            this.btnMinimize.Name = "btnMinimize";
            this.btnMinimize.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 35);
            this.btnMinimize.TabIndex = 0;
            this.btnMinimize.Text = "X";
            this.btnMinimize.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.btnMinimize.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnClose_Click);
            // 
            // main_form
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(((int)(((byte)(83)))), ((int)(((byte)(179)))), ((int)(((byte)(230)))));
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(926, 563);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panelNews);
            this.Controls.Add(this.panel1);
            this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.Name = "main_form";
            this.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Text = "mainform";
            this.Load += new System.EventHandler(this.main_form_Load);
            this.panel1.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panel2.ResumeLayout(false);
            ((System.ComponentModel.ISupportInitialize)(this.pictureBox1)).EndInit();
            this.panelNews.ResumeLayout(false);
            this.panelNews.PerformLayout();
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panel2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.PictureBox pictureBox1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnClose;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Panel panelNews;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label labelNews;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button btnMinimize;
    }
}
```

Comment: Код формы в студию :-)

Comment: @PavelPopov, прикреплю сейчас

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалите эту строчку

```
this.btnMinimize.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.btnClose_Click);
```

Вы, вероятно, создали `btnMinimize` скопировав `btnClose`.